# HTML5 foo.currentTime=1 not working when loaded from server chrome

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

If I load from the local file system, I can seek using

```
foo.currentTime = 2;
foo.play();
```

I get expected results.   However if I load from the server, the seek fails, and the audio plays from the beginning.  I have tried the 'oncanplaythrough' event.  Here is my code:

```
var myID = '1111'
var audioElementString = '<audio type="audio/mpeg" id=' +'"' + myID + '"' + '></audio>'
$('body').append(audioElementString);
var audio = document.getElementById(myID);
//audio.src = "contentAssets/audio/some_file.mp3"; // this loads and seeks fine
audio.src = "http://bar.com/mypath/file"; // this loads and plays, but does not seek

audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
    alert("can play through")
    audio.currentTime=3;
    audio.play();
});
audio.load();
```

Comment: `audio` is not defined when you set `audio.src`.  Your example code will never work.

Comment: Off-topic: You can use `'<audio id="' + myID + '">` instead of `'<audio id=' +'"' + myID + '"' + '>`

Answer (score 2):

Solved, we added Accept-Ranges = bytes to the response header.

Comment: +1 – I'm surprised that this doesn't seem to exist in any of the documentation I've looked through over the last few days.  Our CDN isn't responding with this header and I was wondering why I couldn't seek audio files served from there.  PS, don't forget to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[dt1000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612275/dt1000) has the correct answer.  I have been looking through many different forums for the reason why Chrome will not allow audio.currentTime to be set if streaming an mp3 from PHP and this is the answer that works.  Add this to PHP:

```
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
```

By the way, Firefox and IE do not need the above header to set audio.currentTime.  But Chrome needs it.  Chrome will also not let you move the audio tag slider control without the above header.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, this was the correct answer for me on PHP development server.